# Azure DevOps ordering the release stages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

How can I order the different deploy environments. Just for display purposes.
Currently we have it stand like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

development--test-acceptation--production

I already edited the release pipeline and moved development up, but when saving and going back it still not in the order I want it.
[image]

Comment: Agree with @Shayki Abramczyk, after you move the stage up or down, it will affect the next release pipeline and will not change the current release pipeline order.https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sxaf.png   I try to use REST API to change the finished release pipeline,  and I get the following error https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6oAV.png

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below answer could help you solve your question? If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave comment here :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you move the stages up/down it will reflect only in the next releases, you can't order the stages of finished releases.

Comment: I actually created a new release to change the order of the release tasks , but it still dos not let me change the order!

Comment: @haddassahS it's a sign you need to move to YAML pipelines 

Comment: and do waht?
I'm new at azure DeVos...

Comment: do your release with yaml. see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: ok , I'll look into it , thanks.
in two words , what's the diff. between Classis & YAML  pipelines? and why did my comment made you think , I should move to YAML pipelines?

Comment: thank you for the help, I managed to it!

Comment: Oh good, if you still want more info just say :)

Answer (score 9):

Edit your Release Pipeline. Each of your stages will currently have the Pre-deployment conditions > Trigger set to *After release*. You need to change the subsequent stages to be *After stage* and select the previous stage in the sequence. For example if I want to set my UAT Deployment to be after DEV Deployment;

Before;
[image]
After;
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can move stages Up and Down in the stage settings. However, it reflects only in the next release.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit this specific release also. Go to the Pipelines > Release > This specific relaese.

Then choose to edit the relaese.

This will then only have effect on this one. You also need to edit the main release template. Like you mentioned: eg Pipelines > Relaeses > Edit your release.

Comment: Where can I change the main release template? I am new to devops, sorry if you feel its a junior question

Comment: Like you already mentioned in your question. Normally that will now be ok.

Answer (score 0):

so,
what I had to do is as fallows.

first of all I mikes up , I thought I'm tiring  to reorder the pipelines stages
we I really meant on reordering the pipeline staging TASKS.

so I clicked on the stage an got this window
[image]
then I clicked on the left top on the  *edit the release pipeline*
[image]
an got to the next window
[image]
then I clicked again on the stage 1 rectangle
and got to the next window
[image]
an with the sight of the 14 dots on the side of every task I was able finally to rearrange the order of the tasks!

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue this week and it turned that you need to trigger the Release from a build Pipeline and then the stages will be on a horizontal line like you want it.